# Add lint to CI and mark a build fail when lint produces errors for Android Studio projects

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, lint

I need the Gradle build to be marked as a failure and it should be stopped automatically if running lint gives me an error. I made the changes in code as required but it did not result in any change.

Code:

```
lintOptions {
    // set to true to turn off analysis progress reporting by lint
    quiet true
    // if true, stop the gradle build if errors are found
    abortOnError true
    // if true, only report errors
    ignoreWarnings false
  }
```

Also apart from it, I need to add lint to CI. The CI software I use is Jenkins. SO I need to configure their android linting plugin of Jenkins such that the build is stopped and marked Failure if Lint gives an error.

I am very new to lint and CI, so please provide a detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the Lint Jenkins plugin. Just put something this in your JenkinsFile.

```
try {
    sh './gradlew lint'
} finally {
    step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: 'app/build/reports/staticAnalysis/lint/', fingerprint: true])
}
```

ArtifactArchiver is just to collect artifacts after lint check.